# Gnuplot plotting timelime cuts xtics at certain point

Tags: plot, gnuplot

When I try to plot a timeline showing Treasury yields, Gnuplot does not list all dates on the x axis.
See the following picture of the plot:
[image: Plot]
Gnuplot cuts the xtics after 1995-Jun and does not show any further date. My data looks like:

```
1993-01-04 5.9
1993-01-05 5.9
1993-01-06 5.94
1993-01-07 6.05
..
1996-12-27 6.09
1996-12-30 6.1
1996-12-31 6.21
```

And here is my gnuplot config file:

```
set terminal latex
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set output "5yr-yields.tex"

set xrange ["1993-01-04":"1996-12-31"]
set yrange [4:8]
set xtics format "%Y-%b"

unset mxtics
set xtics ("1993-06", "1992-12", "1993-06", "1993-12", "1994-06", "1994-12", "1995-06", "1995-12", "1996-06", "1996-12")

set size 1.4,1 
set xlabel "date"
set ylabel "\\rotatebox{90}{5-year treasury yield}" rotate by 270
plot "5yr-yields.dat" using 1:2 index 0 notitle with lines smooth csplines
```

I want gnuplot to list 1995-Dec, 1996-Jun, and 1996-Dec as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I solved my issue. When leaving out the line `set size 1.4,1`, the desired dates appear on the x axis. But the dates are overlapping each other because the graph is horizontally not big enough.

How can I scale the graph without the size parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
plot "5yr-yields.dat" using 2:xtic(1) index 0 notitle with lines smooth csplines
```

Comment: Results in `gnuplot> plot "5yr-yields.dat" using 2:xtic(1) index 0 notitle with lines smooth csplines
                                                                                         ^
         line 0: Need full using spec for x time data`